# Java Big O notation of 3 nested loops of log(n)

Tags: java, loops, complexity-theory, big-o, nested-loops

What would the Big O notation be for the following nested loops?

```
     for (int i = n; i > 0; i = i / 2){
        for (int j = n; j > 0; j = j / 2){
           for (int k = n; k > 0; k = k / 2){
              count++;
           }
        }
     }
```

My thoughts are:
each loop is `O(log2(n))` so is it as simple as multiply

```
O(log2(n)) * O(log2(n)) * O(log2(n))  =  O(log2(n)^3)
```

Comment: My assumption also would be  `O(log2(n)^3)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

One way to figure out the big-O complexity of nested loops whose bounds do not immediately depend on one another is to work from the inside out.  The innermost loop does O(log n) work.  The second loop runs O(log n) times and does O(log n) work each time, so it does O(log<sup>2</sup> n) work.  Finally, the outmost loop runs O(log n) times and does O(log<sup>2</sup> n) work on each iteration, so the total work done is O(log<sup>3</sup> n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: what is the correct notation?  O(log2(n) ^ 3) or the way you have it?  or are they both acceptable?

Comment: I've seen this written both ways.  I personally like log^3 n in the style of sin^2 x, though go with whatever convention is used in context.

Comment: The notation for `log<sup>2</sup> n` could be confused for `log log n`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right.

Easy way to calculate -

```
for(int i=0; i<n;i++){ // n times 
    for(int j=0; j<n;j++){ // n times
    }
}
```

This example of simple nested loop. Here Big-O of each loop O(n) and it is nested so typically O(n * n) which is O(n^2) actual Big-O. And in your case -

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i = i / 2){ // log(n)
     for (int j = n; j > 0; j = j / 2){ // log(n)
         for (int k = n; k > 0; k = k / 2){ // log(n)
           count++;
         }
     }
}
```

Which is in nested loop where each loop Big-O is `O(log(n))` so all together complexity would be `O(log(n)^3)`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, your assumption is correct. You can show it methodically like the following:

[image]